# How to stop my Mac from cloning MP3 files on my USB stick?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, file, mp3

Whenever I move my MP3 files to my USB and play it in the car, the files get cloned. For example:

Sia - Chandelier

Then the clone looks like

.Sia - Chandelier

The clones don't actually work. They're simply the MP3 file names. Whenever I select them in my car, it skips to another song that doesn't have . before it. So on my Mac OSX, the MP3 look normal, and have no clones, but once I plug in the USB to my car, every song has its own clone.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete them manually a lot of them will reappear at eject. .DS_Store, trashes, fseventsd & spotlight files especially.

There have been a number of software solutions over the years, most only partially successful. BlueHarvest was about the best I'd tried until recently, but wasn't 100% effective.

I'm currently testing [CleanMyDrive](http://macpaw.com/cleanmydrive), freeware, though they are using it as a bit of an advert for CleanMyMac for your internal drives, but you can ignore that. So far it seems to be fairly effective, but still misses the trash files every so often.

Answer (score -1):

The "clones" are osx system files that are not supposed to show up (should be hidden). This is true in general for files starting with ".", that might be visualised on other operative systems, like Windows. If you have no way to change the settings of your mp3 reader to avoid visualising those files, I guess you'll have to find some way to avoid the problem (like deleting the files manually: to visualise them: https://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/).